# openpyxl - comment.author not visible in xlsx file

Tags: python, openpyxl

Usually when you write a comment in Excel it highlights the author name and then starts the actual comment for a cell.

But, when i try creating a comment with openpyxl, the Author name is not visible.

```
comment_copy = openpyxl.comments.Comment(text='blah',author='someone')
ws["A3"].comment = comment_copy
```

The resulting comment in the xlsx file only has the value "blah" in cell A3 ( No Author name)

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it by the following code:

```
from openpyxl.comment import Comment
cell_comment = Comment("text","author")
cell.comment = cell_comment
```

Answer (score -1):

it dosent add a comment, but rather a note instead to the actual excel cell

Comment: do you have any idea how to add comment to excel using openpyxl not note.